# A page has multiple UITextField the keyboard cannot be hidden

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield, rx-swift

There is a UIScrollView, contentView of scrollView have a UINibView, UINibView have three UITextField:

Action of first UITextField: display a custom view;
Action of second UITextField: show system keyboard;
Action of third UITextField: display a custom view.

Click the second one first, then click the first, the keyboard cannot be hidden at this time.

```
kehuiInfoView.dateInput.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin)
            .subscribe { _ in
                weakSelf?.view.endEditing(true)
                weakSelf?.kehuiInfoView.dateInput.resignFirstResponder()
                weakSelf?.datePicker.show()
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: If you show your custom views by adding them to the text fields' inputViews then everything will be far easier to deal with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your text field is supposed to use a date picker for its input, you can consider using this: https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools/blob/main/Tools/UITextField%2BWheeledDatePicker.swift

With the above, you could for example call:

```
let date = textField.wheeledDatePicker(initial: Date(), formatter: dateFormatter) { $0.datePickerMode = .date }
```

Which will handle bringing up and dismissing the date picker for you.